# How do you load a CSV file into a flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, csv, flutter, dart

I'm trying to load a csv file into my flutter app as a list that I can scroll through on the app. This will be my third page of the app so please mind the navigator early in the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:demo_2/signin.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:demo_2/therapist.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Resources"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          hoverColor: Colors.green,
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate back to first screen when tapped.
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text(
            'Go back!',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TableLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableLayoutState createState() => _TableLayoutState();
}

class _TableLayoutState extends State<TableLayout> {
  List<List<dynamic>> data = [];
  loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/Austin.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = const CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
    print(csvTable);
    data = csvTable;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          onPressed: () async {
            await loadAsset();
            //print(data);
          }),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Table Layout and CSV"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Table(
          columnWidths: {
            0: FixedColumnWidth(100.0),
            1: FixedColumnWidth(200.0),
          },
          border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0),
          children: data.map((item) {
            return TableRow(
                children: item.map((row) {
              return Container(
                color:
                    row.toString().contains("NA") ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    row.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList());
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In my pubspec.yaml file I have I have the following dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  csv: ^4.1.0
```

for my assets in pubspec.yaml I have the following:

```
assets:
    - assets/Austin.csv
```

Here are the first few lines of the CSV I want to display titled "Austin.csv" and located in my /assets folder:

```
Names,Provider Type,Location,Phone Number,Financial,Accepted Insurance Plans,Issues,Specialties,Mental Health Areas,Sexualities,Faiths,Ages Treated,Communities,Treatments
Donna Rich,"Clinical Social Work/Therapist , LCSW","1007 Mopac Circle Suite 201 Austin, TX 78746",(512) 649-0079,"['Cost per Session:$150', 'Sliding Scale:Yes', 'Out of Network']",['Out of Network'],"['Chronic Pain', 'Codependency', 'Coping Skills', 'Divorce', 'Grief', 'Hoarding', 'Parenting', 'Peer Relationships', 'School Issues', 'Self Esteem', 'Sleep or Insomnia', 'Substance Use']","['Depression', 'Anxiety', 'Relationship Issues']",[],"['Bisexual', 'Lesbian', 'Gay']",[],"['Adults', 'Adolescents / Teenagers (14 to 19)', 'Children (6 to 10)']",[],"['Family / Marital', 'Play Therapy', 'Psychodynamic']"
Greg Keilin,"Psychologist , PhD","3355 Bee Caves Road Suite 104 Austin, TX 78746",(512) 201-2569,"['Cost per Session:$175', 'Sliding Scale:Yes', 'Out of Network']","['Out of Network', 'Out of Network']","['Anxiety', 'Bipolar Disorder', 'Codependency', 'Coping Skills', 'Divorce', 'Emotional Disturbance', 'Family Conflict', 'Grief', 'Infidelity', 'Internet Addiction', 'Life Coaching', 'Life Transitions', 'Marital and Premarital', ""Men's Issues"", 'Peer Relationships', 'Sex Therapy', 'Sexual Abuse', 'Sexuality, diversity, prof. training', 'Sleep or Insomnia', 'Stress', 'Suicidal Ideation', 'Trauma and PTSD', ""Women's Issues""]","['Depression', 'Self Esteem', 'Relationship Issues']","['Mood Disorders', 'Personality Disorders', 'Thinking Disorders']","['Bisexual', 'Lesbian', 'Gay']",[],"['Elders (65+)', 'Adults']","['Bisexual Allied', 'Gay Allied', 'Lesbian Allied']","['Clinical Supervision and Licensed Supervisors -', 'Cognitive Behavioral (CBT)', 'Culturally Sensitive', 'EMDR', 'Eclectic', 'Family / Marital', 'Family Systems', 'Feminist', 'Integrative', 'Interpersonal', 'Mindfulness-Based (MBCT)', 'Multicultural', 'Positive Psychology', 'Psychodynamic', 'Relational', 'Strength-Based', 'Therapeutic Use of Self', 'Trauma Focused']"
Spectrum Services,"Psychologist , PhD , LPC , LCSW , LMFT","Spectrum Services 8105 Shoal Creek Blvd, Ste B Austin, TX 78757 Call Spectrum Services",(512) 271-4877,"['Cost per Session:$60 - $150', 'Sliding Scale:Yes']",[],"['Anger Management', 'Autism', 'Behavioral Issues', 'Bipolar Disorder', 'Career Counseling', 'Child or Adolescent', 'Chronic Impulsivity', 'Coping Skills', 'Depression', 'Developmental Disorders', 'Divorce', 'Emotional Disturbance', 'Family Conflict', 'Intellectual Disability', 'Learning Disabilities', 'Life Coaching', 'Obsessive-Compulsive (OCD)', 'Parenting', 'Peer Relationships', 'Relationship Issues', 'School Issues', 'Self Esteem', 'Self-Harming', 'Sleep or Insomnia', 'Transgender']","[""Asperger's Syndrome"", 'Anxiety', 'ADHD']","['Impulse Control Disorders', 'Mood Disorders', 'Thinking Disorders']","['Bisexual', 'Lesbian', 'Gay']",[],"['Elders (65+)', 'Adults', 'Adolescents / Teenagers (14 to 19)', 'Preteens / Tweens (11 to 13)', 'Children (6 to 10)', 'Toddlers / Preschoolers (0 to 6)']","['Bisexual Allied', 'Cancer', 'Gay Allied', 'Lesbian Allied', 'Transgender Allied']","['Coaching', 'Cognitive Behavioral (CBT)', 'Family / Marital', 'Family Systems', 'Mindfulness-Based (MBCT)', 'Psychological Testing and Evaluation', 'Solution Focused Brief (SFBT)']"
Topaz ABA,"MA , BCBA , LBA","Topaz ABA Austin, TX 78746 Call Katie Worrell",(512) 488-3767,"['Aetna', 'Anthem', 'BlueCross and BlueShield', 'Cigna', 'Magellan', 'Out of Network']","['Aetna', 'Anthem', 'BlueCross and BlueShield', 'Cigna', 'Magellan', 'Out of Network']","['ADHD', 'Child or Adolescent', 'Coping Skills', 'Developmental Disorders', 'Dual Diagnosis', 'Intellectual Disability', 'Learning Disabilities', 'Oppositional Defiance', 'Peer Relationships']","['Autism', 'Behavioral Issues', ""Asperger's Syndrome""]",[],[],[],"['Adolescents / Teenagers (14 to 19)', 'Preteens / Tweens (11 to 13)', 'Children (6 to 10)', 'Toddlers / Preschoolers (0 to 6)']",[],"['Applied Behavioral Analysis', 'Intervention', 'Play Therapy']"
Kim Wolfgang,"Licensed Professional Counselor , MS , LPC","K Wolfgang Counseling 4422 Packsaddle Pass Suite 103 Austin, TX 78745",(512) 649-1224,"['Cost per Session:$140+', 'Out of Network']","['Out of Network', 'Out of Network']","['Family Conflict', 'HAES (Health at Every Size) and body image concern', 'Relationship Issues']","['Eating Disorders', ""Women's Issues"", 'Anxiety']",[],[],[],['Adults'],"['Cancer', 'Queer Allied']","['Eclectic', 'Family Systems', 'Mindfulness-Based (MBCT)', 'Relational']"
```

The ideal list would have the Name, Phone Number, Financials, and Issues in the list that can be scrolled through. If you need my main.dart file I can edit the post and include it.

Comment: Still Can't understand what is the issue you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did. I couldn't use the DataTable widget off the bat, though I may try and reformat for a demo, so I had to use the csv package. My updated code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:demo_2/opening_page.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:demo_2/virtual_therapist.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

class ThirdScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ThirdScreenState createState() => _ThirdScreenState();
}

class _ThirdScreenState extends State<ThirdScreen> {
  List<List<dynamic>> data = [];
  Future<List<String>> loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/test_austin.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
    print(csvTable);
    data = csvTable;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          onPressed: () async {
            await loadAsset();
            //print(data);
          }),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Resources"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Table(
          columnWidths: {
            0: FixedColumnWidth(110.0),
            1: FixedColumnWidth(125.0),
            2: FixedColumnWidth(165.0)
          },
          border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0),
          children: data.map((item) {
            return TableRow(
                children: item.map((row) {
              return Container(
                  child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  row.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Netflix'),
                ),
              ));
            }).toList());
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I still don't understand the stateful vs stateless stuff because I'm new, but this stuff worked for me. my dependecies were simply csv: ^4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Use the **'[DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html)'** widget to show rows and columns of data. Please refer to the Flutter docs for documentation and 'Widget of the Week' video at  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html

The Flutter docs also recommend to use [PaginatedDataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PaginatedDataTable-class.html) if you have a lot of data.